# How to Add Context to an Image, that is served via a Go Handler?

Tags: go, handler

i have a Website managed in Go. On one of them, i serve QR-Codes, which can be used to Login to the Page.

I added the QR-Codes to the HTML-File like this:

```
    <img alt="Failed to load QR-Code" src="/qr.png/{{.Loc}}">
```

and added the Handler as follows:

```
    http.HandleFunc("/qr.png/", qrWrapper(checkLocation, checkPortAndPrintError, qrcodeHandler))
```

The Problem is, a different QR-Code for each supported Location needs to be generated. Currently i put it on the Website directly via the `ExecuteTemplate`-Function.

The Page the QR-Code is on, has the Location in the URL:

```
/token/Würzburg
```

As Example for the Location "Würzburg".

The Problem is, the User can just read out the HTML-Body in his Browser and access the Image directly.

Is it somehow possible, to serve the Image in the `<img>`-Tag, without having to actually write the Location in it? Bypassing the actual Site can be Security-Risk. Maybe you can somehow add Context to the Request?  My qrWrapper cuts out the Location in the GET-URL. Is there a better solution? Maybe add a Filter in the Handler, so just the Webpage can access it, without putting it in the Website?

I hope its clear what i want to achive.

Below are all 3 Handlers:

```
func qrcodePageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    loc, ok := r.Context().Value("loc").(authentification.Location)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error while creating qrcode-Page: Failed to load Location"), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    err := executeTemplateFunc("qr", qrPage, w, qrPageContent{
        Loc:   loc.Name,
        Timer: RefreshTimer,
    })
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error while creating qrcode-Page: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

func qrWrapper(lf locationCheckerFunc, cf portCheckerFunc, handler http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        loc := path.Base(r.URL.Path)
        locStruct, ok := lf.authenticate(loc)
        if strings.Contains(loc, "token") || !ok {
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        } else {
            if !cf(w, *r, QrPort, http.StatusForbidden) {
                return
            }
            ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "loc", locStruct)
            handler(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
        }
    }
}

func qrcodeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    loc, ok := r.Context().Value("loc").(authentification.Location)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error while creating qrcode: Failed to load Location"), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    _, qrcode, err := qrCodes.QRCode(loc, fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", SrvUrl, "?token="), qrRecoveryLevel, 400)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error while creating qrcode: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    _, err = w.Write(qrcode)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error while showing qrcode: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: When you generate the page, you can encrypt the location, and build the URL using that encrypted string, which then you decrypt in the handler.

Comment: @PenélopeStevens The Problem is, the actual Website needs to refresh itself after x Seconds. Thats why that page has a Header-Element which does that. The Image itself doesnt have that

Comment: @BurakSerdar The Problem is not, that the Location is actually visible to the User. But that the User can access the Image directly without being on the QR-Page. Thats why i asked, if i can add somehow a Context to it (like i do in my Wrapper)

Comment: A URL is a URL. You can't really figure out if a URL is being loaded because of a link on a page, or because someone entered the URL.

Comment: It seems to me that you might use a one-time token to produce a QR code and then expire it, not allowing that token to be reused.  A bit of a hassle but it would solve your problem.